# NOAA empty/missing data

Tags: python, noaa

Trying to pull hourly precipitation data from NOAA but get empty data sets {} for certain stations. I know there is data for the missing station because I can request it through the web page.

The request

```
r = requests.get('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=PRECIP_15&stationid=COOP:170273&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-31', headers={'token':Token})
```

More helpful info, both these stations should have **PRECIP_HLY**.

> COOP:170273 COOP:170275

I know this by running
'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets?stationid=COOP:170273&limit=50'

But only coop:170273 retrieves data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Some stations (including airports) are not included in the database. Check Local Climatological Data instead.